# D3 pick nodes needed for graphics

Tags: javascript, layout, svg, d3.js, nodes

I have a graph on the screen and all the data that is needed is in a variable called `jsonData`, this being my way to avoid a JSON-File stored seperately on a server.
Now the `jsonData` contains more than i really want to show at the beginning, so I have to select the needed nodes.
The idea is to have a root node and show all the nodes directly connected with it and the conections between them.
Is there any simple possibility to do this?
Maybe I can change the line

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(jsonData.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);
```

because it doesn't need to select all of them, but how can I pick the ones needed?
I have an array in the background that contains all the needed links and I'm up to writing a part that will store the connected nodes.
I can't give this new array directly to the `svg.selectAll`-part because otherwise the links will crash (they refer to the number of the node by it's original position in the bigger array).
Any hints on that? I couldn't find any examples for this on via Google-research, but if you can spot something out there in the net, just feel free to answer with the link!

Thanks in advance,
    David

Comment: So basically it goes like this. Instead of using the jsonData.nodes as your data you use a variable and you collect those nodes in that variable. Basically you can have a callback function to set the data in that variable and the just do svg.selectAll(".node").data(myVar). Now how you precisely pick those nodes is your business: the ones with certain values would be my guess...

Comment: You're right, that seems to be the way to go. But how can I fix up the links afterwards? there is still a couple of links in the style of `{"source":16,"target":7,"value":4}`, with `source` and `target` referring to the position in the old array.

Comment: of course you do the same... for the links you will use another list of links (array of links) that you assign to the list of links related to your force directed layout... (because I think we talk force directed)... However here you will have to decide how to add those links, as in my experience a link that's already on the screen doesn't need to be repainted...you will have a lot of fun trying to get this right, but in the end I guess you will succeed...Links are just objects that have 2 properties: source and target...you have to be careful with directed and undirected graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getNodesIndex(searchedFor){
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.nodes.length; i++){
        if(jsonData.nodes[i].name == searchedFor){
            return i;   
        }
    }//for
}

function getNetParts(searchedFor){
    reqNodes = null;
    reqNodes = [];
    reqLinks = null;
    reqLinks = [];

    var index = getNodesIndex(searchedFor);
    reqNodes.push(jsonData.nodes[index]);   

    for(var y = 0; y < jsonData.nodes[index].connections.length; y++){
        //stores every node connected with the main node in reqNode
        reqNodes.push(jsonData.nodes[jsonData.nodes[index].connections[y]]);    
    }

    for(var z = 1; z < reqNodes.length; z++){                   
        //circle through stored Nodes
        for(var c = 0; c < reqNodes[z].connections.length; c++){    
            //inspect all of their connections
            for(var w = 0; w < reqNodes.length; w++){
                //check all stored reqNodes for the one linked
                if(jsonData.nodes[reqNodes[z].connections[c]].name == reqNodes[w].name)           { 
                    //the node is available at reqNodes?
                    var source = null; 
                    var newLink = {
                        "source":z,
                        "target":w,
                        "value":1,
                    };                          
                    reqLinks.push(newLink);                 
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

And then `update()` just deletes anything on the screen, gets the new data and rebuilds the visualisation.
Just in case anyone has the same trouble... ;)